# When compiling solution, previously working assembly reference / using no longer works

Tags: c#, using, assembly-references, visual-studio-2010

I added a assembly as reference to my project, I imported its namespace with a `using` directive, and no problem occurs; IntelliSense finds the namespace, too.

When I try to compile the solution or go into debug mode, suddenly this error appears:

> *Cannot find the type or namespace name `BrightIdeasSoftware`; probably missing a using directive or an assembly reference.*

How is this possible?

Comment: Where is the DLL? I don't suppose you put it in the *output* directory, did you? (The output directory which will be cleaned when you build...)

Comment: Try selecting the reference in the Solution Explorer, and changing the Copy Local property to True (and maybe try the Embed Interop Types too)

Comment: I try to put the DLL there and out in another directory, but same result! Now is inside the debug folder, so close to the exe file!

Comment: @Alfie Error 1 Can not embed interop types of the assembly because it lacks the attribute 'ImportedFromTypeLibAttribute' or attribute 'PrimaryInteropAssemblyAttribute'

no way!

Comment: @Hans Passant you are right! the problem was the client profile!
The question is resolved! may thanks!